# How to fix ngOnInit() not fired after router.navigate

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 application and I want to navigate between modules but the ngOnInit method does not run when I return to the initial page.

I have two pages, in app-routin.module

```
  { path: 'Home', loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'Login', loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
```

inside Login page have a button (Button1) that executes the following code

```
this.router.navigate(['/Home']);
```

inside Home page have a button (Button2) that executes the following code

```
this.router.navigate(['/Login']);
```

I write this page in browser URL 'http://localhost:8100/Login'.

```
console log => 'enter to LOGIN ngOnInit'
```

when I press the Button1

```
console log => 'enter to HOME ngOnInit'
```

when I press the Button2

```
nothing log
```

when I press the Button1

```
console log => 'enter to HOME ngOnInit'
```

I tried to run the navigation inside `this.zone.run` but it still does not work

EDIT:
work fine if use `[routerLink]="['/Login']"` instead of programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngOnInit get's called on initialization of the component, and your component is already created when you go away and return to it.

In order to get OnInit called you need to destroy the component or use a different technique to get your script run when you return to the page.

Other Ionic life cycle events are:

```
ionViewDidLoad

ionViewWillEnter

ionViewDidEnter

ionViewWillLeave

ionViewDidLeave

ionViewWillUnload
```

Comment: Ok thanks inside ionViewDidEnter()

but why does it work with [routerLink]="['/Login']" and not with this.router.navigate(['/Login']); ??

Comment: I think because routerLink reload page but router navigate just changes the component.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and I solved it using this

```
this.navigateTo('/url');
```

instead of this

```
this.navigateTo('url');
```

In my case I don't use square brackets and it only works in some cases.